# Mostrar dato concreto de JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Estoy intentando recuperar uno de los datos que me trae una lista de mi controlador en JavaScript, la lista se ve así:

`Console.log(result)` ->

```
0:{nombreCliente: '', cuitDni: '', numeroPedido: '972022', items: '', pathImagenes: '/temporal/972022_80919677_0044-00028590_2022-09-27_07-43-00.jpg', …}
1:{nombreCliente: '', cuitDni: '', numeroPedido: '972022', items: '', pathImagenes: '/temporal/972022_80919677_0044-00028590_2022-09-27_07-43-13.jpg', …}
2:{nombreCliente: '', cuitDni: '', numeroPedido: '972022', items: '', pathImagenes: '/temporal/972022_80919677_0044-00028590_2022-09-27_07-43-21.jpg', …}
3:{nombreCliente: '', cuitDni: '', numeroPedido: '972022', items: '', pathImagenes: '/temporal/972022_80919677_0044-00028590_2022-09-27_07-43-27.jpg', …}
4:{nombreCliente: '', cuitDni: '', numeroPedido: '972022', items: '', pathImagenes: '/temporal/972022_80919677_0044-00028590_2022-09-27_07-43-45.jpg', …}
```

Lo que necesito solamente es `pathImagenes`. Para esto intenté lo siguiente:

```
console.log(result[0].pathImagenes);
console.log(result[0].pathImagenes.toString());
console.log(result[0].pathImagenes[0].toString());
console.log(JSON.stingify(result[0].pathImagenes));
console.log(JSON.stingify(result.pathImagenes));
console.log(result.pathImagenes);
let obj = JSON.parse(result)
console.log(obj['pathImagenes']);
```

Incluso

```
for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      console.log(result[i]["pathImagenes"]);
}
```

Pero todas estos intentos me trajeron lo mismo que ven arriba, la misma lista.

¿En qué estoy fallando?, ¿Cómo se hace correctamente?

Comment: puedes agregar que resulta de `console.log` de las funciones _success_ y _error_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Más sencillo sería ingresar a los valores de tu objeto `result` con [**`Object.values()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) para posteriormente recorrerlos con [**`map()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) a los valores y ya con esto ingresas al valor correspondiente de cada uno de ellos.

Para que me entiendas mejor, mira lo que ocurre con `Object.values(result)`:

```js
Object.values(result);
```

```js
let result = {
  0: {
    nombreCliente: '',
    cuitDni: '',
    numeroPedido: '972022',
    items: '',
    pathImagenes: '/temporal/972022_80919677_0044-00028590_2022-09-27_07-43-00.jpg',
  },
  1: {
    nombreCliente: '',
    cuitDni: '',
    numeroPedido: '972022',
    items: '',
    pathImagenes: '/temporal/972022_80919677_0044-00028590_2022-09-27_07-43-13.jpg',
  },
  2: {
    nombreCliente: '',
    cuitDni: '',
    numeroPedido: '972022',
    items: '',
    pathImagenes: '/temporal/972022_80919677_0044-00028590_2022-09-27_07-43-21.jpg',
  },
  3: {
    nombreCliente: '',
    cuitDni: '',
    numeroPedido: '972022',
    items: '',
    pathImagenes: '/temporal/972022_80919677_0044-00028590_2022-09-27_07-43-27.jpg',
  },
  4: {
    nombreCliente: '',
    cuitDni: '',
    numeroPedido: '972022',
    items: '',
    pathImagenes: '/temporal/972022_80919677_0044-00028590_2022-09-27_07-43-45.jpg',
  },
};

let pathImagenes = Object.values(result)
console.log(pathImagenes);
```

Si te das cuenta, estamos ingresando a todos los valores de tu objeto `result`, y estos valores **también son objetos**, en la cual, podemos recorrerlo con `map()` e indicar a qué valor específico queremos ingresar (en tu caso, a `pathImagenes`).

```
Object.values(result).map(item => item.pathImagenes);
```

---

Código:

```js
let result = {
  0: {
    nombreCliente: '',
    cuitDni: '',
    numeroPedido: '972022',
    items: '',
    pathImagenes: '/temporal/972022_80919677_0044-00028590_2022-09-27_07-43-00.jpg',
  },
  1: {
    nombreCliente: '',
    cuitDni: '',
    numeroPedido: '972022',
    items: '',
    pathImagenes: '/temporal/972022_80919677_0044-00028590_2022-09-27_07-43-13.jpg',
  },
  2: {
    nombreCliente: '',
    cuitDni: '',
    numeroPedido: '972022',
    items: '',
    pathImagenes: '/temporal/972022_80919677_0044-00028590_2022-09-27_07-43-21.jpg',
  },
  3: {
    nombreCliente: '',
    cuitDni: '',
    numeroPedido: '972022',
    items: '',
    pathImagenes: '/temporal/972022_80919677_0044-00028590_2022-09-27_07-43-27.jpg',
  },
  4: {
    nombreCliente: '',
    cuitDni: '',
    numeroPedido: '972022',
    items: '',
    pathImagenes: '/temporal/972022_80919677_0044-00028590_2022-09-27_07-43-45.jpg',
  },
};

let pathImagenes = Object.values(result).map(item => item.pathImagenes);
console.log(pathImagenes);
```

Comment: Estaba por publicar lo mimo, buena explicación ;)

Comment: Buenas, deberia mostrarse igual incluso si lo utilizo dentro de `success`, no? Porque no sé qué está ocurriendo que tampoco me lo está mostrando correctamente. Me encanta tu respuesta.

Comment: Lo siento, `success` me refiero a la funcion exitosa con `ajax`.

Comment: Ah claro, no habría problema, mientras el objeto cumpla con estas características (objetos dentro de un objeto), iría todo bien, y si tienes algún otro problema, podrías especificarlo en otra pregunta (ya que eso sería un tema diferente a esta, y mi respuesta perdería sentido). Recuerda verificar la respuesta marcándole al ✔️ si te sirvió para que tu pregunta esté como respondida y los demás sepan que mi respuesta te sirvió, saludos.

Comment: Excelente, funcionó perfecto. Muchas gracias!